# Unable to select Ribbon chart Y-axis data range on Power BI due to Y-axis config option not available

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

Plotting issue on Ribbon chart due to configuration issue of Y-axis range

Power BI version:

[image]

[image]

My data is

[image]

What we need is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have selected Line and stacked column chart and configured Y-axis then changed ribbon chart not it showing as below.

1) Configuring Y-axis

[image]

2) After configuration changed ribbon chart as result what we want
[image]